# Is critical phenomena feasible for finite molecular systems?

Tags: phase-transitions

We know that critical phenomena plays an important role to study phase transition for solid state systems. But it seems that the critical phenomena is always associated with infinite systems (e.g. crystal structure). The question is that is critical phenomena feasible for molecular systems that have finite number of atoms?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe? I am not that familiar with critical phenomena, but I know about lattice vibrations and I know that Jahn-Teller distortions occur in isolated molecules. See e.g. here [example](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Coordination_Chemistry/Structure_and_Nomenclature_of_Coordination_Compounds/Coordination_Numbers_and_Geometry/Jahn-Teller_Distortions#:%7E:text=The%20Jahn%2DTeller%20effect%20is,those%20of%20the%20equatorial%20bonds.).

I don't really know if this is a critical phenomena. It is definitely a phase transition with spontaneous symmetry breaking and the formation of a Goldstone mode (one of distortions is "frozen in", i.e. a normal mode becomes zero-frequency). Maybe you didn't already know about this and it can help you in your search! If not, cheers anyway!

Ty